# Is there any condition while applying law of exponents?

Tags: complex-analysis, exponentiation, real-numbers

${[(-3)^2]}^\frac{1}{2}$ = ${(-3)^2}^\frac{1}{2}$ = $-3^1$ = $-3$

But counted other way it is

$9^\frac{1}{2} = \surd{9} = 3$

where I went wrong?

Comment: This is because $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$. In general for any even power I suppose.

Comment: Ya that's true but $(x^m)^n = x^{mn}$ too.

Comment: @Sry:  Haven't you just proved otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second answer is the right one, i.e., ${[(-3)^2]}^\frac{1}{2}=3$. In your first attempt, you are trying to use the identity $(x^m)^n=x^{mn}$, which holds only true if both $x^m, x^n\in\mathbb{R}$. This is not the case here, as $\sqrt{-3}$ is not a real number.

As a general rule (i.e., for arbitrary $m,n\in\mathbb{R}$), the exponent laws are only valid for non-negative $x$.

Comment: Thanks... This helped me to realize what I was missing.